# react-native-notifications crashing the app when notification received

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, react-native-notifications

I am using react-native-notifications library to implement notification in my app with message cloud firebase , I have followed all guidelines in the documentation,
[For react-native-notifications library](https://wix.github.io/react-native-notifications/docs/installation-android)
[For firebase cloud messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)

So when I go to firebase counsel and send a test notification message, nothing happened the app just closed or could call it crash, I have added `firebase-analytics` to help me with debug what the problem and this what I got when I sent test notification message:

```
  Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/util/zzq;
       at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver.onReceive()
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3177)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1653)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

here is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Platform, View } from 'react-native'
import { Notifications } from 'react-native-notifications'




export default class PushNotificationManager extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.registerDevice()
        this.registerNotificationEvents()
    }

    registerDevice = () => {
        Notifications.events().registerRemoteNotificationsRegistered(event => {
            // TODO: Send the token to my server so it could send back push notifications...
            

            console.log('Device Token Received', event.deviceToken)
        })
        Notifications.events().registerRemoteNotificationsRegistrationFailed(event => {
            console.error(event)
        })

        Notifications.registerRemoteNotifications()
    }

    registerNotificationEvents = () => {
        Notifications.events().registerNotificationReceivedForeground((notification, completion) => {
            console.log('Notification Received - Foreground', notification)
           
            })
            // Calling completion on iOS with `alert: true` will present the native iOS inApp notification.
            completion({ alert: false, sound: false, badge: false })
        })

        Notifications.events().registerNotificationOpened((notification, completion) => {
            console.log('Notification opened by device user', notification)
           
            console.log(`Notification opened with an action identifier: ${notification.identifier}`)
            completion()
        })

        Notifications.events().registerNotificationReceivedBackground((notification, completion) => {
            console.log('Notification Received - Background', notification)
            
            // Calling completion on iOS with `alert: true` will present the native iOS inApp notification.
            completion({ alert: true, sound: true, badge: false })
        })

        Notifications.getInitialNotification()
            .then(notification => {
                console.log('Initial notification was:', notification || 'N/A')
            })
            .catch(err => console.error('getInitialNotifiation() failed', err))
    }

    render() {
        const { children } = this.props
        return <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>{children}</View>
    }
}
```

in  `console.log` it consoling the token  and in

```
Notifications.getInitialNotification()
                .then(notification => {
                    console.log('Initial notification was:', notification || 'N/A')
                })
```

it keep consoling `'N/A'`

and I wrapped the previous code with the whole app root:

```
<PaperProvider theme={theme}>
            <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
  /* here*/     <PushNotificationManager>
                    <NavigationContainer theme={theme}>
                        
                      <RootStackScreen />
                
                    </NavigationContainer>
/* here*/        </PushNotificationManager>
            </AuthContext.Provider>
        </PaperProvider>
```